# Error installing php 71 with homebrew on my mac

Tags: php, laravel-5, homebrew, laravel-valet

I have been developing with Vallet for some time now. Today i wanted to update laravel 5.4 to 5.5. Before doing so i run `composer global update`. Causing Vallet to stop working.

Fist i tried to do the following:

`cd ~/.composer/`

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) vendor`

source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/getting-valet-not-found-error

I did not solve the issue. Then i decided to reinstall Vallet. Hereby i did the following:

I followed this: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/321

Stop and uninstall services

```
sudo brew services stop php71 dnsmasq nginx
brew uninstall php71 dnsmasq nginx
```

Remove related config files and valet home folder

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/etc/php /usr/local/etc/nginx /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
sudo rm -r ~/.valet /var/root/.valet
```

Install services i tried this:

```
brew install php71
```

```
$ brew tap homebrew/php
$ brew install php71
```

```
brew install homebrew/php/php71
```

All gave the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ mblivier$ brew install homebrew/php/php71 
==> Installing php71 from homebrew/php Error: The following formula: php71 
cannot be installed as a binary package and must be built from source.

Install the Command Line Tools:xcode-select --install
```

I new in this and don't know how to solve this. Any suggestions how to install php and go further with reinstalling Vallet?

- homebrew is installed and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need xcode to build php, so first run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

to install xcode and later you can `brew install php71`

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I did. Also runed ```brew install php71``` and started the php71. ```MacBook-Pro:applications mblivier$ brew services start php@7.1
==> Successfully started `php@7.1` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php@7.1)```.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I did. Also runed ```brew install php71``` and started the php71. ```MacBook-Pro:applications mblivier$ brew services start php@7.1
==> Successfully started `php@7.1` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php@7.1)```. But when i ask ```php -v``` i comes back with ```-bash: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory```. Is there something i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***This is answer for your comment, I can't post as comment, need to post because is length limited.***

There is one of two things going on here, either you didn't install PHP, or PHP is installed and not currently in any of system aware paths. First I would try to find PHP and make sure it exists:

```
$ find / -name php -type f
```

You should see something like:

```
/path/to/your/php/bin/php
```

If PHP binary does exist, check your path:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If it does not exist, recompile php.

If PHP exists on your system, make sure the path to the /bin/php file is included. You can edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add the custom path like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/php/bin/
....  
export PATH
```

Then save and reload the file to ensure your current session has access to new path changes:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

With any luck you can now do a `php -v` and see the version response.

Comment: root, Thanks for your reaction. I got php working. Thanks for the help so far. After this i ran in a other issue. I created a question for it as well. Do you also know the solution for this? thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494486/laravel-valet-wont-install