# Laravel valet won't install

Tags: laravel-5, installation, laravel-valet, valet

I had some problems with valet. I have used it for a while no. No i like to reinstall valet. But i don't get it installed.

This is what i did before (whit help) [Error installing php 71 with homebrew on my mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477632/error-installing-php-71-with-homebrew-on-my-mac)

After this i got my homebrew running:
brew list:

```
brew list

apr     c-ares      glib        libev       libpq       mysql       python      webp
apr-util    curl-openssl    gmp     libevent    libsodium   nghttp2     readline    xz
argon2      freetds     icu4c       libffi      libssh2     openldap    rtmpdump
aspell      freetype    jansson     libidn      libtiff     openssl     sqlite
autoconf    gdbm        jemalloc    libmetalink libtool     pcre        tidy-html5
brotli      gettext     jpeg        libpng      libzip      php     unixodbc
```

Next to this i did:

```
composer global require laravel/valet
```

With this result:

```
MacBook-Pro:applications [user]$ composer global require laravel/valet
```

```
Changed current directory to /Users/[user]/.composer
Using version ^2.3 for laravel/valet
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing laravel/valet (v2.3.3): Downloading (100%)
Generating autoload files
```

It seems he changes the directory to `/Users/[user]/.composer` 
I don't know why.

But when i try to install i get the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:applications [user]$ valet install
-bash: valet: command not found
```

I new in this but think it has to do with my path:

This what i currently have in `vim ~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/users/[user]/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

At the end i like to install valet. No it does not react on `valet install`. Help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thinks its duplicate, try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085102/laravel-valet-install-not-found

Comment: you should add composer bin directory to your system path: `export PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin`, it should work after that.